# Cannot avoid suspend on Xfce

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xfce, sleep, autologin

Okay i have had an issue for the past few weeks I cannot figure out. I have been trying to prevent screen sleep/logout on some industrial screen that should staty awake permanently, with autologin, etc.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5, and I have installed Xfce, that's it.

I've been playing a lot around gsettings, lightdm settings, dconf, xset, and everything, but there is always something that messes up.

Since yesterday, I succeeded to prevent sleep after 5 minutes of inactivity by settings gschema overrides on org.gnome.desktop.session/screensaver, but after 20 minutes it enters suspend mode (i guess), with black screen and the cursor upper-left, with no wi-fi, usb interactions, etc. I chose to mask the sleep.Target, hybrid-sleep.Target, hibernate.target and suspend.target like recommended in many other pages, but now, after 20 minutes, it seems that another Desktop Environment is being executed, I don't even have access to a terminal on that new GUI.

I don't know what to do guys, I'm open to any lightweight GUI. I just want something light, simple, and that stays awaken permanently with an autologin user.

Comment: What are your settings in the XFCE Power Manager?  I believe you can disable sleep/suspend/hibernate from there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GracefulRestart, I found something  that works out, I'm putting it as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something, I don't know at what point it is good, I  haven't checked if everything in this is mandatory, but it worked.

```
echo_blue "Disabling screensaver and lock setup"
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
echo "[org.gnome.desktop.session]" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.session.gschema.override
echo "idle-delay = 0" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.session.gschema.override
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.screensaver user-switch-enabled
echo "[org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.override
echo "lock-enabled = false" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.override
echo "lock-delay = 0" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.override
echo "ubuntu-lock-on-suspend = false" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.override
echo "user-switch-enabled = false" | tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.override
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```